# Why is my concat method adding millions of rows to my pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

**The Issue:** My method below adds several million unwanted rows to my `df`.

`len` before method: `707,864`
After method: `6,370,776`

data source: https://data.cityofchicago.org/Buildings/Building-Permits/ydr8-5enu

The data has multiple columns for contact info in this format: `CONTACT_1_TITLE`, `CONTACT_1_NAME`, `CONTACT_2_TITLE`,`CONTACT_2_NAME` all the way to 15.

The order of contact titles and names (if present, sometimes they aren't) are random. For example, the `ARCHITECT` title might be in the first title column, the second, third, etc... There are other variants of the title, such as `ARCHITECT AS OWNER`

I want to create a new dataframe, `df_arch`, that contains every row from the previous frame in which a variant of the title `ARCHITECT` is present. Except for the extra `TITLE`, `NAME` and contact information associated with them (they're their own columns too)

In `df_arch`, I want a single column, `TITLE`, that includes the architect's title. I want another column, `NAME`, that includes the architect's name, which is always in the cell immediately to the right of the title.

To capture all this, I have the following:

```
title = pd.concat([df[col] for col in df.filter(regex='CONTACT_\d_TYPE')], axis=0)
name = pd.concat([df[col] for col in df.filter(regex='CONTACT_\d_NAME')], axis=0)

ID = pd.concat([df[col] for col in df. filter(like='ID')], axis=0)
permit_num = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='PERMIT#'))
permit_type = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='PERMIT_TYPE'))
review_type = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='REVIEW_TYPE'))
app_start_date = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='APPLICATION_START_DATE'))
issue_date = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='ISSUE_DATE'))
processing_time = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='PROCESSING_TIME'))
street_num = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='STREET_NUMBER'))
street_dir = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='STREET DIRECTION'))
street_name = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='STREET_NAME'))
street_suffix = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='SUFFIX'))
work_desc = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='WORK_DESCRIPTION'))
building_fee_paid = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='BUILDING_FEE_PAID'))
zoning_fee_paid = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='ZONING_FEE_PAID'))
other_fee_paid = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='OTHER_FEE_PAID'))
subtotal_paid = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='SUBTOTAL_PAID'))
building_fee_unpaid = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='BUILDING_FEE_UNPAID'))
zoning_fee_unpaid = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='ZONING_FEE_UNPAID'))
other_fee_unpaid = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='OTHER_FEE_UNPAID'))
subtotal_unpaid = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='SUBTOTAL_UNPAID'))
building_fee_waived = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='BUILDING_FEE_WAIVED'))
zoning_fee_waived = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='ZONING_FEE_WAIVED'))
other_fee_waived = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='OTHER_FEE_WAIVED'))
subtotal_waived = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='SUBTOTAL_WAIVED'))
total_fee = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='TOTAL_FEE'))
reported_cost = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='REPORTED_COST'))
ward = pd.concat(df[col] for col in df.filter(like='WARD'))


df = pd.concat([title,name, ID, permit_num, permit_type, review_type,\
                app_start_date, issue_date, processing_time, street_num,\
                street_dir, street_name, street_suffix, work_desc,\
                building_fee_paid, zoning_fee_paid, other_fee_paid,\
                subtotal_paid, building_fee_unpaid, zoning_fee_unpaid,\
                other_fee_unpaid, subtotal_unpaid, building_fee_waived,\
                zoning_fee_waived, other_fee_waived, total_fee, reported_cost,\
                ward], axis=1)

df.columns = ['title', 'name', 'ID', 'permit_num', 'permit_type','review_type',\
              'app_start_date', 'issue_date', 'processing_time','street_num',\
              'street_dir','street_name','street_suffix','work_desc',\
              'building_fee_paid','zoning_fee_paid','other_fee_paid',\
              'subtotal_paid','building_fee_unpaid','zoning_fee_unpaid',\
              'other_fee_unpaid','subtotal_unpaid','building_fee_waived',\
              'zoning_fee_waived','other_fee_waived','total_fee','reported_cost',\
              'ward']
```

This is the block of code that adds several million rows, and I can't figure out why. I've included some sample data below:

```
    ID  PERMIT# PERMIT_TYPE REVIEW_TYPE APPLICATION_START_DATE  ISSUE_DATE  PROCESSING_TIME STREET_NUMBER   STREET DIRECTION    STREET_NAME SUFFIX  WORK_DESCRIPTION    BUILDING_FEE_PAID   ZONING_FEE_PAID OTHER_FEE_PAID  SUBTOTAL_PAID   BUILDING_FEE_UNPAID ZONING_FEE_UNPAID   OTHER_FEE_UNPAID    SUBTOTAL_UNPAID BUILDING_FEE_WAIVED ZONING_FEE_WAIVED   OTHER_FEE_WAIVED    SUBTOTAL_WAIVED TOTAL_FEE   CONTACT_1_TYPE  CONTACT_1_NAME  CONTACT_1_CITY  CONTACT_1_STATE CONTACT_1_ZIPCODE   CONTACT_2_TYPE  CONTACT_2_NAME  CONTACT_2_CITY  CONTACT_2_STATE CONTACT_2_ZIPCODE   CONTACT_3_TYPE  CONTACT_3_NAME  CONTACT_3_CITY  CONTACT_3_STATE CONTACT_3_ZIPCODE   CONTACT_4_TYPE  CONTACT_4_NAME  CONTACT_4_CITY  CONTACT_4_STATE CONTACT_4_ZIPCODE   CONTACT_5_TYPE  CONTACT_5_NAME  CONTACT_5_CITY  CONTACT_5_STATE CONTACT_5_ZIPCODE   CONTACT_6_TYPE  CONTACT_6_NAME  CONTACT_6_CITY  CONTACT_6_STATE CONTACT_6_ZIPCODE   CONTACT_7_TYPE  CONTACT_7_NAME  CONTACT_7_CITY  CONTACT_7_STATE CONTACT_7_ZIPCODE   CONTACT_8_TYPE  CONTACT_8_NAME  CONTACT_8_CITY  CONTACT_8_STATE CONTACT_8_ZIPCODE   CONTACT_9_TYPE  CONTACT_9_NAME  CONTACT_9_CITY  CONTACT_9_STATE CONTACT_9_ZIPCODE   CONTACT_10_TYPE CONTACT_10_NAME CONTACT_10_CITY CONTACT_10_STATE    CONTACT_10_ZIPCODE  CONTACT_11_TYPE CONTACT_11_NAME CONTACT_11_CITY CONTACT_11_STATE    CONTACT_11_ZIPCODE  CONTACT_12_TYPE CONTACT_12_NAME CONTACT_12_CITY CONTACT_12_STATE    CONTACT_12_ZIPCODE  CONTACT_13_TYPE CONTACT_13_NAME CONTACT_13_CITY CONTACT_13_STATE    CONTACT_13_ZIPCODE  CONTACT_14_TYPE CONTACT_14_NAME CONTACT_14_CITY CONTACT_14_STATE    CONTACT_14_ZIPCODE  CONTACT_15_TYPE CONTACT_15_NAME CONTACT_15_CITY CONTACT_15_STATE    CONTACT_15_ZIPCODE  REPORTED_COST   PIN1    PIN2    PIN3    PIN4    PIN5    PIN6    PIN7    PIN8    PIN9    PIN10   COMMUNITY_AREA  CENSUS_TRACT    WARD    XCOORDINATE YCOORDINATE LATITUDE    LONGITUDE   LOCATION
0   1830273 100190752   PERMIT - SIGNS  SIGN PERMIT 10/16/2007  03/05/2008  141.0   6349    S   COTTAGE GROVE   AVE INSTALL BUILDING SIGN   70.0    75.0    0.0 145.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 145.0   SIGN CONTRACTOR JAS. D. AHERN CO.   CHICAGO X   IL  60623   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2000.0  20-23-100-005   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   2060019 100296510   PERMIT - ELECTRIC WIRING    EASY PERMIT WEB 06/15/2009  06/15/2009  0.0 10000   N   BESSIE COLEMAN  DR  LOW VOLTAGE 50.0    0.0 0.0 50.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 50.0    CONTRACTOR-ELECTRICAL   ELITE ELECTRIC CO. INC. MELROSE PARK    IL  60160   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 70000.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 76.0    NaN 41.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   1671981 100108067   PERMIT - ELECTRIC WIRING    EASY PERMIT WEB 04/17/2006  04/17/2006  0.0 7535    N   HERMITAGE   AVE ADD CIRCUITS FOR COMPUTERS. 40.0    0.0 0.0 40.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 40.0    CONTRACTOR-ELECTRICAL   PACE SYSTEMS, INC.  NAPERVILLE  IL  60563-  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   2832499 100696131   PERMIT - ELECTRIC WIRING    EASY PERMIT WEB 03/20/2017  03/20/2017  0.0 150 N   RIVERSIDE   PLZ LOW VOLTAGE CABLING FOR 18TH & 25TH FLOOR BUILD OUTS.   150.0   0.0 0.0 150.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 150.0   CONTRACTOR-ELECTRICAL   PAUL M CARUSO   LOMBARD IL  60148-  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 39600.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 28.0    2801.0  42.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   3053734 100830913   PERMIT - ELECTRIC WIRING    EASY PERMIT WEB 07/17/2019  07/17/2019  0.0 4001    N   RAVENSWOOD  AVE ATT IL01735G NR UPGRADE - 850: SWAP (3) EXIST LTE RRUS12 W/ (3) PROPOSED RRUS4478-B5 W/ 2ND FIBER IN P4. ONLY CONNECT 2 PORTS OF RADIO TO ANTENNA, OTHER 2 PORTS TO BE CAPPED OFF.ADD (1) 12 PAIR FIBER TRUNK TO EXISTING FC12 BOX ON SHELTER WALL.SELF RET - P45G NR UPGRADE - 850: ADD (3) 25A BREAKERS, (1) 20A BREAKER, (1) 6630, AND UPPER/LOWER SFPS. 300.0   0.0 0.0 300.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 300.0   CONTRACTOR-ELECTRICAL   BRIAN K PETERSEN    ELGIN   IL  60124-  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 15000.0 14-18-420-031   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 6.0 60200.0 47.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies your concat for title,name and ID.

```
for i,j in zip(cols,[title,name, ID, permit_num, permit_type, review_type,\
                app_start_date, issue_date, processing_time, street_num,\
                street_dir, street_name, street_suffix, work_desc,\
                building_fee_paid, zoning_fee_paid, other_fee_paid,\
                subtotal_paid, building_fee_unpaid, zoning_fee_unpaid,\
                other_fee_unpaid, subtotal_unpaid, building_fee_waived,\
                zoning_fee_waived, other_fee_waived, total_fee, reported_cost,\
                ward]):
    print(i,len(j))
```

output:

```
title 6383331
name 6383331
ID 6383331
permit_num 709259
permit_type 709259
review_type 709259
app_start_date 709259
issue_date 709259
processing_time 709259
street_num 709259
street_dir 709259
street_name 709259
street_suffix 709259
work_desc 709259
building_fee_paid 709259
zoning_fee_paid 709259
other_fee_paid 709259
subtotal_paid 709259
building_fee_unpaid 709259
zoning_fee_unpaid 709259
other_fee_unpaid 709259
subtotal_unpaid 709259
building_fee_waived 709259
zoning_fee_waived 709259
other_fee_waived 709259
total_fee 709259
reported_cost 709259
ward 709259
```

Maybe use another approach to deal with those columns
also, 6383331/709259 = 9, maybe another clue